# Qt. Boost - lib. MinGW. Does not link

Tags: c++, qt, boost, mingw

I need to use boost serialization.

error: [debug/main.o] Error 1

```
LIBS += -LC:/LIB/BOOST/lib
```

Does not help

Comment: If it helps, in my `pro` file I have the path in quotation marks and I think you have to specify the dll with `-l`. Like `-L"C:/MY_PATH" -lboost_serialization`. If you have a static lib, try to pass it directly to `LIBS`. For example: `LIBS + = "C:/MY_PATH/mylib.a"`

Comment: And the error message you got, was just that? There's nothing more?

Comment: The real error message will normally be above the Error 1 line.

Comment: Error is only only one line